# Live data visualisation in tableau public

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I am using Tableau Public. I have a made a dashboard, but the dataset that will change daily. Is it possible to get the dashboard updated as per changes in the data file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The situation is like this. I have Tableau public. We are having a survey for 10 days. Each day the data will get updated. So the dashboard we have made has to change accordingly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only possible way to keep a tableau public dashboard updated is by putting your data into a Google Sheet.

There are various methods for this from python, to other methods.  Once in the google sheet build your workbook on this Google sheet as the data source in tableau desktop and publish to your public Tableau profile.

You cannot select the specific time for refresh, but Tableau states they update it daily, and you can request ad-hoc to put it into a que for refresh.

Tableau Documentation for this Topic:
https://community.tableau.com/s/tableau-public-faq#subhead19a